# Can a scala class be instantiated in same way as java

Tags: scala

Below class does not compile, if I declare Functions as an object instead of class I can run the method fac using Functions.fac(3) . Does it make sense in scala to attempt to run a class like this ? How can the below code be modified so that it runs without changing to object instead of class ?

```
class Functions {

  def fac(n : Int) = {
    var r = 1;
    for(i <- 1 to n) r = r * i;
    r
  }
     def main(args:Array[String]) = {
      Functions f = new Functions();

      print(f.fac(3));
  }

}
```

Comment: It makes perfect sense to create a new object with `new` and that code *should* compile (even if perhaps not run) .. make sure you are asking the question you wish to ask -- e.g. what "doesn't work" with that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most obvious problem in your code is that you have `Functions f = ...`.  This is Java syntax, so in Scala you need it to say `val f: Functions = ...`

Second, Scala makes a larger distinction between static and non-static things than Java.  In Scala, something that's static (such as a `main` method) is declared in an object.  So you should separate the `object` (static) parts from the `class` parts.

Third, your `fac` function could be more simply written as `(1 to n).product`.

Finally, you don't need the semi-colons.

```
class Functions {
  def fac(n: Int) =
    (1 to n).product
}

object Functions {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val f: Functions = new Functions()
    print(f.fac(3))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java and Scala implement static functions very differently.  In Java you add the static identifier, while in Scala you put the method in the Object companion.